# Issue with Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

When I try to create crystal report "rssdk" automatically added to my file name which cause file not found error. 
Can any one suggest why this is the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the related code 
where you are facing the issue related to it...
I guess you are not able to find the file at your location and the it fails to load that file in

server.mappath("your path");